# Want to hide a button by it's id/class, by clicking a checkbox

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

```css
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ div#span-advanced-search {
    background: white;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 564px;
    padding: 10px;
    visibility: visible;
    left: -573px;
    top: 11px;
}
```

```html
<label for="toggle-1" class="ds-drop-down" role="button" data-tooltip="Show search options"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-1"></input>

<div id="span-advanced-search">
 <label>Education Level:</label> <input type="text"/><br></br>
 <label>Type of Learning Material:</label> <input type="text"/><br></br>
 <label>Difficulty Level:</label> <input type="text"/><br></br>
 <label>Author:</label> <input type="text"/><br></br>
 <input class="ds-button-field " name="submit" type="submit" i18n:attr="value" value="xmlui.general.go">
    <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
    <xsl:text>
         var radio = document.getElementById(&quot;ds-search-form-scope-container&quot;);
         if (radio != undefined &amp;&amp; radio.checked)
         {
               var form = document.getElementById(&quot;ds-search-form&quot;);
               form.action=
     </xsl:text>
               <xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text>
               <xsl:value-of select="/dri:document/dri:meta/dri:pageMeta/dri:metadata[@element='contextPath']"/>
               <xsl:text>/handle/&quot; + radio.value + &quot;</xsl:text>
               <xsl:value-of select="/dri:document/dri:meta/dri:pageMeta/dri:metadata[@element='search'][@qualifier='simpleURL']"/>
               <xsl:text>&quot; ; </xsl:text>
               <xsl:text>

                     }
               </xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>

     </input>   
</div>


<input class="ds-button-field " name="submit" type="submit" i18n:attr="value"
                                       value="xmlui.general.go">
  
</input>
```

I want to hide the button `ds-button-field` when I am checking the `checkbox->"toggle-1"`.How can I do that using **css** and using id/class name of that button? Initially that button must be visible.

Comment: i think u should use javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/* initial state */
.ds-button-field {
   display: block;
}

/* button hidden if the sibling checkbox is checked */
#toggle-1:checked ~ .ds-button-field {
   display: none;
}
```

As a side note `<input ...></input>` should be `<input ... />`

Answer (score 0):

```
.ds-button-field {
   display: block;
}
#toggle-1:checked ~ .ds-button-field {
   display: none;
}
```

Kepp the two input buttons adjacent to each other